# How to set flag in a select statement in a SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, flags

I got Employee table where I select employee records when employee id is supplied, with in which I have to enable a flag if the employee record exists with 1 otherwise 0. I'm trying to accomplish this using the following script:

```
DECLARE @FLAG INT
DECLARE @EMPID VARCHAR(10)

SELECT  CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS @FLAG, 
        E.EMPID,
        E.EMPNAME, 
        E.DESIGNATION 
FROM 
    EMPLOYEE E LEFT JOIN  
    GEO23.EMPLOYEEDETAILS ED ON E.EMPID = ED.EMPID 
WHERE E.EMPID = @EMPID
ORDER BY E.EMPID DESC
```

But this results in error. Can somebody please help. Please note I'm an amateur in SQL

Comment: `But this results in error.` doesnt help, what error you have?

Comment: That has so many problems.  What are you trying to do?  as @flag is not proper syntax - that is an alias.   Cannot have a count with a group by.   Exits where - do you mean in GEO23?  Why would you order by EMPID if you are searching on one. You may be new to SQL but you should be able to write a better question than that by now.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a flag or you can return results in SQL Server, but not both.  So, the syntax that works for the query you have written:

```
SELECT @FLAG = (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM EMPLOYEE E LEFT JOIN 
     GEO23.EMPLOYEEDETAILS ED
     ON E.EMPID = ED.EMPID
WHERE (E.EMPID = @EMPID)
ORDER BY E.EMPID DESC;
```

I left the query as you wrote it, but it has numerous issues:

- The `order by` is unnecessary, because it only returns one row.
- The `left join` is unnecessary, because it keeps all the rows in the first table, and you are only using a `count()`.

So, an equivalent version is:

```
SELECT @FLAG = (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM EMPLOYEE E
WHERE E.EMPID = @EMPID;
```

For this query, I would recommend an index on `employee(empid)`.

Comment: How can I change my query in such a manner that I query the result only if the result of this @flag > 0

Comment: @dsfasdfadf . . . You would calculate the flag and then add another query that uses it in the `where` clause.

Comment: @dsfasdfadf Update the question with what you need as that is something different from where this started.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming EMPID is unique, you should just need to do something like this.  If it finds the record it will be 1, otherwise it will be 0.

```
DECLARE @FLAG INT
DECLARE @EMPID VARCHAR(10)

SELECT @FLAG = COUNT(*)
FROM EMPLOYEE E
WHERE (E.EMPID = @EMPID)
```